# Get rows above and below (neighbouring rows) a certain row, based on two criteria SQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join, union

Say I have a table like so:

```
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
|id | level |score |      timestamp      |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
| 4 |   1   |  70  | 2021-01-14 21:50:38 |
| 3 |   1   |  90  | 2021-01-12 15:38:0  |
| 1 |   1   |  20  | 2021-01-14 13:10:12 |
| 5 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-13 12:32:11 |
| 7 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-14 17:15:20 |
| 8 |   1   |  55  | 2021-01-14 09:20:00 |
| 10|   2   |  99  | 2021-01-15 10:50:38 |
| 2 |   1   |  45  | 2021-01-15 10:50:38 |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
```

What I want to do is show 5 of these rows in a table (in html), with a certain row (e.g. where id=5) in the middle and have the two rows above and below it (in the correct order). Also where level=1. This will be like a score board but only showing the user's score with the two above and two below.
So because scores can be the same, the timestamp column will also need to be used - so if two scores are equal, then the first person to get the score is shown above the other person.

E.g. say the user is id=5, I want to show

```
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
|id | level |score |      timestamp      |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
| 4 |   1   |  70  | 2021-01-14 21:50:38 |
| 8 |   1   |  55  | 2021-01-14 09:20:00 |
| 5 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-13 12:32:11 |
| 7 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-14 17:15:20 |
| 2 |   1   |  45  | 2021-01-15 10:50:38 |
| 1 |   1   |  20  | 2021-01-14 13:10:12 |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
```

Note that id=7 is below id=5

I am wondering does anyone know a way of doing this?

I have tried this below but it is not outputting what I need (it is outputting where level_id=2 and id=5, and the other rows are not in order)

```
((SELECT b.* FROM table a JOIN table b ON b.score > a.score OR (b.score = a.score AND b.timestamp < a.timestamp)
  WHERE a.level_id = 1 AND a.id = 5 ORDER BY score ASC, timestamp DESC LIMIT 3)
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT b.* FROM table a JOIN table b ON b.score < a.score OR (b.score = a.score AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp)
  WHERE a.level_id = 1 AND a.id = 5 ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC LIMIT 2)) 
order by score
```

If it is easier to output all rows in the table, say where level = 1, so it is a full score board.. and then do the getting a certain row and two above and below it using PHP I'd also like to know please :) ! (possibly thinking this may keep the SQL simpler)?

Answer (score 1):

The values for id 5 and LIMIT must be calculate beforehand and passed on to the query, because LIMIT must have fixed values or you have to use a prepared statement

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`id` int, `level` int, `score` int, `timestamp` varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`id`, `level`, `score`, `timestamp`)
> VALUES
>     (4, 1, 70, '2021-01-14 21:50:38'),
>     (3, 1, 90, '2021-01-12 15:38:0'),
>     (1, 1, 20, '2021-01-14 13:10:12'),
>     (5, 1, 50, '2021-01-13 12:32:11'),
>     (7, 1, 50, '2021-01-14 17:15:20'),
>     (8, 1, 55, '2021-01-14 09:20:00'),
>     (10, 2, 99, '2021-01-15 10:50:38'),
>     (2, 1, 45, '2021-01-15 10:50:38')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `id`, `level`, `score`
> FROM
>     ((SELECT 
>         `id`, `level`, `score`, 1 orderby
>     FROM
>         table1 a
>     WHERE
>         level = 1
>             AND `score` > (SELECT 
>                 `score`
>             FROM
>                 table1
>             WHERE
>                 id = 5)
>     ORDER BY `score` ASC
>     LIMIT 2) UNION ALL (SELECT 
>         `id`, `level`, `score`, 2 orderby
>     FROM
>         table1 a
>     WHERE
>         id = 5) UNION ALL (SELECT 
>         `id`, `level`, `score`, 3 orderby
>     FROM
>         table1 a
>     WHERE
>         level = 1
>             AND `score` <= (SELECT 
>                 `score`
>             FROM
>                 table1
>             WHERE
>                 id = 5)
>             AND id <> 5
>     ORDER BY `score` DESC
>     LIMIT 3)) t1
> ORDER BY orderby ASC , score DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | level | score
> -: | ----: | ----:
>  4 |     1 |    70
>  8 |     1 |    55
>  5 |     1 |    50
>  7 |     1 |    50
>  2 |     1 |    45
>  1 |     1 |    20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38f2aafd22f35363d7e7d090d8e31f28)*

Comment: Hi, I am getting error "subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: With your provided data, this works, if you want me to debug it you must built a dbfiddle or update mine and give me the new link

Comment: I have created a fiddle with my real data - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=0a03ccfefbfad1964716c359eede7825 (the fiddle is not giving me the same error as phpmyadmin, but it isn't outputting anything)

Comment: That is  because you made some error while coyiing my code see here is a fixed version https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ba3015120a7395ea8d3f916262e4a56b  please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Oh so you mean do this in all different queries instead of just one? Also I am a bit confused by your fixed version as it doesn't output what I need - it doesn't give the two rows below

Comment: yes there was a error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=9744a7b180ba2b6861ae302bb9d87dd7

Comment: Thanks, but now I've noticed that it gives two rows above and three below, but I need two below..

Comment: your example shows 6 rows result set and not 5, else change the limit from3 to 2

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I just noticed I must have wrote that wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to adjust the SQL now to get total points for each user for all levels.. the code is here but I can't get it to work.. could you maybe have a look please? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a95b465514eff3941c237bc2ca647f5f

Comment: it is quite simple https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5f2a919c731fb5bd889dbc87ee71233b

Comment: Yeah that's what I had done too from my fiddle above, but that only gives me one row.. I am trying to get the same as before (a row with two above and two below) but only with total points instead of where level=1. Do you know how I'd do this?

Comment: that is a new question, so you have to ask a new quiestion so thqat i can answer it and can also ganin reputation. but i can tell you that in your code sample are no rows with a summarized score of 185

Comment: Hi, I've asked a new question here and updated the code sample to include rows with scores higher than 185 :) hope you can help, thanks! https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283454/get-rows-above-and-below-a-certain-row-based-on-two-criteria-sql-with-sum

Comment: Hi sorry to pester you but not sure if you saw my last comment.. it'd be great if you could have a look at my new question  ^ ! thanks

Comment: as you removed the answer tag from my answer, please don'zt expect any help

Comment: oh sorry I didn't realise I had done that!! I must have done that by accident, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT z.id, z.level, z.score, z.`timestamp`
  FROM ( SELECT w.*
              , @num := @num+1 AS num
              -- just to get the 'num' for middle line: 
              , IF( w.id = 5, @hit := @num, NULL ) AS unused
           FROM table AS w
           WHERE @num := 1 -- UDV initialization
             AND w.level = 1
           ORDER BY w.score DESC
                  , w.`timestamp` ASC
       ) AS z
 WHERE z.num BETWEEN @hit-2 AND @hit+2 -- how many rows above and below  
 ORDER BY z.num ASC
;
```

Subselect enumerates rows ordered by score and timestamp and stores the `@num` value for given ID in the user defined variable `@hit`. An outer select just filter the rows that are within the given range.

Dbfiddle works pretty bad with UDVs so you have to test that code on the real DB.